# Ajax driven paginated content, php response to _escaped_fragment_

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, pagination

Second day of reading about Google SEO...still confused about this part...what content am I supposed to deliver to their crawler through PHP?

I have a blog site, the index page has a limit of 5 articles which are a preview to the full article (I think this is more or less standard).  The pagination right now is `/index.php?pg=1`, `/index.php?pg2`...although I'm about to change it to a hash parameter `/index.php#pg=1`.

Each one of the articles has their own full page with comments, and each article content coming from MySQL has its own full HTML inside a column (coming from CMS with a WYSIWYG editor).  I know I can play around with Google's "Fetch as Google" option...but the original question being...what to serve from my database when the request comes in as:

```
if(isset($_GET['_escaped_fragment_'])){
    //how to structure the data for the crawler?
}
```

Do I structure it to look the same as inside the `content` div on the original page?  Do I use `new DOMDocument()`?  The original query is:

```
    $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT id, title, itemText, category FROM blog UNION SELECT id, title, itemText, category FROM items ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $lim, $limit");
```

I understand this might be better suited for webmasters stackexchange question but it deals more with the PHP side of it so please bear with me and help me understand.

Comment: Are you using a blogging system such as WordPress, or is it your own hand-rolled code?

Comment: @KevinNagurski I am designing my own from scratch so all those examples from WP and AngularJS sites don't really help with the PHP side. `http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-64206.html`...is this a good example?  "JShor" just puts the content into an array and returns it to the crawler...is that right?

Comment: That's really based on AJAX applications, is this what yours is, or do you actually go to `/index.php?pg=2`?

Comment: @KevinNagurski If there are more then 5 articles, the user clicks on `NEXT` and is taken to `www.myblog.com/index.php?pg=2`.  I am changing it now to `www.myblog.com/index.php#pg=2` so there will be no page reload, just content update.

Comment: I'd hold fire on that... what you're best doing is keeping that functionality and use JS to intercept the click, load the stuff via AJAX and update the URL with the [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_pushState()_method) method

Comment: @KevinNagurski Yeah, that's possible also, I've looked into that.  Just `e.preventDefault()` on the click and update the content.  But what about the PHP part?  What content do I serve to Google?  Do I recreate the same DOM or just deliver the article content so they don't think I'm cloaking?

Comment: Google do have some ability to execute JS, so you'll probably be fine either way, but I find the best approach is to treat search engines like you'd treat browsers with no JS enabled. You might want to look into writing some `.htaccess` `mod_rewrite` rules so that to the world (and Google) you're serving up `www.myblog.com/page2` etc. It's pretty simple.

Comment: @KevinNagurski I'm not very strong with the server side (.htaccess)...and also I understand graceful degradation/progressive enhancement...but if disabling JS for Google and Facebook is not an option, why should it be for us? :)  There's no reason for someone to surf the web nowadays with JS disabled unless there's some ill intent.